# Когда открываю вкадку Network в Google Chrome создаётся бесконечный поток файлов на собственной вёрстке

Tags: google-chrome

Когда открываю вкладку Network в гугл хром создаётся бесконечный поток файлов на собственной вёрстке, с чем это может быть связанно, и как это решить?

[image: j]

Comment: По стилю названий файлов, похоже что это фейсбук или инстаграм...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В виду того, что не виден код верстки, скажу следующее:

Посмотрите любое видео в ютубе с открытой вкладкой нетворк и вы увидите что периодически появляются запросы, подгружаются кусочки видео, затем плеер их склеивает. Я думаю у вас происходит что-то подобное, т.к. используется формат mp4, может это следствие какого-то скрипта, с функцией которого вы не особо знакомы, можно отключить все скрипты и поочередно повключать их чтобы выявить нужный а уже после, просто прочесть так сказать мануал как и для чего он это делает.

Comment: Да, спасибо, оказывается библиотека jquery
 ( <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> )
 создаёт эти файлы, а я и не знал

Comment: @Invtriangle рад что вы разобрались благодаря моей "подсказке", просьба засчитать ответ либо просто закрыть вопрос (если сейчас не получается, то позже)